# Having trouble using a char in C

Tags: c, char

I'm very new to C and am having an issue with using chars.  I have a large string assigned to

```
char *test = "very large string of characters";
```

When I try to write out the string with 
    printf("%s", test);

it shows me the full string fine, however if I try doing

```
printf("%s", test); 
printf("%s", test);
```

the second printf only displays about 20% of the string.

How can I get test to write out twice without being truncated?

Comment: I don't think this is causing your problem but you could more simple write printf(test);  also I think the stream gets flushed on a newline character.

Comment: Further to what cnicutar (*edit* and chasep255) says, you can also cause the stream to be flushed by adding a new-line to the output, thusly: `printf("%s\n", test);`

Answer (score 4):

Do a `fflush(stdout)` or it may get buffered.

Comment: Also note that writing a newline (`'\n'`) will cause the buffer to be flushed as well.

Comment: @C0deH4cker It may cause a flush - and in many cases does - but is not guaranteed to do so.

Comment: The newline also has the benefit that the output does not run together with the command prompt in terminal applications.

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference if all his code does is printing the string twice. Upon exiting, all buffers are obviously flushed.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves That's right and I was thinking about it. My guess is  that the program isn't exiting normally though.